# Shape key is affecting the normals of faces its not attached to

Tags: normals, shape-keys, vector

[image]

[image]

[image]

It did this after I created a bottom lid blink.
the weird part for me is that the top lid blink was never attached to these vertices but it is affecting the shadows and causes them to go crazy when the value of the bottom lid shape key is changed

Comment: Hello, hard to tell what's happening, maybe share just the head so that we can test? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by selecting the vertex group associated with the bottom lid blink shape key and separating by selection by pressing 'P' then rejoining the objects by selecting the bottom lid and the face in object mode then pressing ' CTRL + J' to join the objects.

No more jittering.